# How to apply animation to all the enumerates beamer

Tags: beamer, animations

How to apply animation ("\pause" command)  to all the enumerates  in a beamer presentation with just one command in premeable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can specify a default overlay specification of `<+->` for each `\item` using the command

```
\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}
```

I don't really recommend this though, since it's generally a bad idea to animate every single list in a presentation.

It's probably preferable to specify the automatic animation on each list separately. This avoids the need for using `\pause` everywhere, but gives you more control:

```
 \documentclass{beamer}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{frame}
 \frametitle{A frame}
 \begin{itemize}[<+->]
 \item First item
 \item Second item
 \item Third item
 \end{itemize}
 \end{frame}
 \end{document}
```